# Display specific data in a wordpress widget/shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, data

I have specific data that I've made available via the REST API using the data access plugin.  I'd like to include this data via shortcodes or something similar in pages in WordPress.

For example, I have some aggregate data - like member counts - that I want to include in a an overview page, so I want to be able to just get the actual piece of data itself - the individual number, so I can place it wherever I want on the page.

Most of the integrations seem to revolve around showing tables of data.

Is this something that's doable in WordPress?  I've been considering changing this site over to Drupal (for other reasons), is this something that's easier to do in Drupal?

Answer (score 1):

In wordpress you can do it using [dataprocessor](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor) extension and [CiviCRM UX](https://github.com/agileware/wp-civicrm-ux/blob/master/USAGE.md#civicrm-data-list-using-the-civicrm-data-processor-shortcode) plugin. You can build the views using [dataprocessor](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor) and use [CiviCRM UX](https://github.com/agileware/wp-civicrm-ux/blob/master/USAGE.md#civicrm-data-list-using-the-civicrm-data-processor-shortcode) plugin to create a shortcode which can be used in wordpress.

Drupal: Yes possible using drupal views and even using [dataprocessor](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/dataprocessor)